# After update,the all-apps icon is missing on palmtop

Tags: updates

After performing an update, the all-apps icon is gone. I need that to launch the Play Store since there was no palmtop icon for that. How do I restore the icon for all apps?

Using Droid Maxx 2 with Android 7.1.1

Comment: Can't you do that from settings > apps > app details and launch from Play store?

Comment: Also from settings > apps > home, see if launcher is disabled or try resetting it

Comment: beeshyams, neither solved it.

Comment: please have screen shot of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The update installed a caret icon at bottom center which acts as the original all-apps icon did. The caret is small enough that I didn't see it at first. Issue resolved.

Comment: Rahul Gopi, the home screen icons persisted after the update. You were misinformed.